# WhatsApp Web Not working in electron app (Update to Google Chrome)

Tags: google-chrome, browser, electron, whatsapp, user-agent

**I can't run whatsapp on my electron browser even after setting useragent to the latest chrome version**
if someone have solution please tell

Answer (score 0):

You can use different user agent like this:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) old-airport-include/1.0.0 Chrome Electron/7.1.7 Safari/537.36
```